# Fantasy book about a young man taking a dream vacation

Tags: story-identification, books

As far as I remember the young man saves enough money at the start of the book to buy a vacation in a Dreamland. He choose a medieval land where magic is pretty common. All I remember is that when he arrived the world feels real to him and I think something/someone is preventing him and all other dream tourists to go back.
So he is trying to discover what he can do to come back. On his journey he meets a girl that helps him.

Comment: Could it be Terry Brooks' [_Magic Kingdom for Sale–Sold!_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Kingdom_for_Sale%E2%80%93Sold!)?

Comment: No, but thanks.

Comment: There were a lot of "people sucked into/caught in games" books when role playing games first came out.  The most similar to your description would be Larry Niven's [_Dream Park_](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/357922.Dream_Park?ac=1&from_search=true).  Was it something like that:  a game/adventure he couldn't get out of?

Comment: No, sorry the book describes it as a vacation in a dreamland and i cant remember any game related stuff.